# Trying to generate a fibonacci sequence into a listbox item

Tags: c#

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtseq.Text);
        int[] array = new int[lbox.Items.Count];
        if (txtseq.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[0] = 0;
                array[1] = 1;
                array[i] = array[i--] + array[i];
                lbox.Items.Add(array[0].ToString() + array[1].ToString() + array[i].ToString());
                
            }

            
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Insert something first");
    }
```

Trying to generate a fibonacci sequence and sending it to a listbox item however i dont understand why its not being added to the listbox as a item in the for

Comment: what are you getting? are you getting an error?  also is this WPF, Windows Forms? we need more details

Comment: its a windows form application where the user types into a textbox the amount of elements he wants on a fibonacci sequence after pressing a button it gets added into a listbox

Comment: When you start your program, you probably don't have any elements in your listbox. Thus `int[] array = new int[lbox.Items.Count];` will create an array of length `0` (because `lbox.Items.Count` is `0`. Thus `for (int i = 2; i < array.Length; i++)` won't execute the loop's body because the condition  `2 < 0` is wrong. You probably want to use `for (int i = 2; i< quantity; i++)` instead

Comment: Furthermore within your loop you have `array[i--]`. That will (once the loop is executed) lead to an infinite loop, because `i--` is decrementing the value of `i`, together with the `i++` in the loop's head, your `i` is never growing, thus your loop condition will never become `false`. You probably want `array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2]` instead

Comment: Ah, and of course you should also initialize your array with size `quantity` ie `int[] array = new int[quantity]`